# RequestDataValueProcessor methods are never called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

First, this is reference to the Spring MVC 3.1.x http://blog.eyallupu.com/2012/04/csrf-defense-in-spring-mvc-31.html, I have attempted to implement RequestDataValueProcessor and added a

```
<bean name="requestDataValueProcessor" class="my.class"/>
```

to my servlet's context file.

I can see from the debug output of the startup that the bean is created, but none of the methods are ever called, the forms on the pages rendered do not contain the special hidden values, and, of course, the HandlerInterceptor sees that and returns a 403 for all POST attempts.

I'm sure that the 3.1.4 release Spring jars are what's in my war. Merely creating a bean with a given name seems awfully... magical. What else might I need to do that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind.

Turns out Maven was dragging in 3.0.x dependencies for Spring due to a transient dependency problem. Forcing massive Spring 3.0 exclusion fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful for others, but bean name is hardcoded in the sources (*RequestContext*), so you should use only *requestDataValueProcessor* as a bean name. For instance is you are using Spring security > 3.2 then:

```
<bean name="requestDataValueProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.servlet.support.csrf.CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor"/>
```